# K8s bitnami/redis with sentinel and LoadBalancer - how to have master endpoint?

Tags: redis, amazon-eks, bitnami

Installed Redis (bitnami/redis) to my EKS and also configured sentinel + LoadBalancer to have an ability to have an access outside EKS.

Here is part of my configuration (I am using AWS):

```
sentinel:
  enabled: true
...
service:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ...
  annotations:
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internal"
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: "eks-redis"
  service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets: subnet-xxx,subnet-yyy
```

It is working, but some times I have an issue related to `READONLY You can't write against a read only replica.`

So my AWS NLB currently returning 2 IPs, one of these IPs is pointing to master and the second - to the replica.

And, sometimes, my application can`t work correctly, when replica IP is using and my app is trying to write to the Redis.

I can`t change my app code.

What is the best solution for this situation?

For now, I know only one - try to use HAproxy. But maybe I am missing something? Maybe it can be implemented more easy?

PS The second question - does redis default service is pointing always to master redis? Or it is also random selection and sometimes I can get slave node?